# How do I calculate percentages from two tables in Django

Tags: python, django, orm

I`m pretty new to the Django Framework and I am stuck at calculating a percentage. Here`s the problem:

I have two tables SocialCase and Donation:

class SocialCase(models.Model):

```
title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
profile = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
organizer = models.TextField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=False)
description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=False)
created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
profile_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='static/images/')
case_tags = models.ManyToManyField('events.Tag')
target_donation = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True)
```

class Donation(models.Model):

```
user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
social_case = models.ForeignKey(SocialCase, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
raised = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True)
```

I want to use a @property method to calculate the percentage between **raised** and **target_donation**

1. The **target_donation** field represents the total money needed for
   this social case. The **target_donation** will be set when the
   Social Case is created.
2. The **raised** field represents the amount of money that has been
   currently raised. The **raised** field will be a dynamic value that
   will increment with each donation

I want to calculate the percentage on the SocialCase model.
How do I bring the **raised** column from Donations model in order to calculate the percentage of each Social Case and output it in the HTML template?

Thank you verry much, and and sorry if this a simple question, I`m still a newbie and couldn`t find anything in the Django Documentation.

Kind regards,
Sergiu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you define a `ForeignKey` it creates a "reverse" field on the related object. You can name this using `related_name`, otherwise it defaults to `<modelname>_set` (modelname is lowercased). In this case, `donation_set`

That's probably what you were missing. The code will be something like

```
@property
def percent_raised(self):

    total = 0.0
    for donation in self.donation_set.all():
        total += float( donation.raised)

    return total / float( self.target_donation) * 100.0
```

It's more efficient in this case but much less generalizable, to calculate the sum of donations in the DB query using an aggregation function. See [the cheat sheet here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/aggregation/) (third example using `Avg`, but in this case you'd want `Sum` not `Avg`)